# when I Try to Create new Post or Page it goes Draft(I can't post Anything)

Tags: debug, publish, draft

I have Done Some Debugging is there:

1, Deactivate Plugins
2, Switch Themes
3, Update plugins & themes
4, update the WordPress version
5, in functions.php :

```
function remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']);
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets' );
```

6,In wp-config.php

```
define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 3600 );     // autosave 1x per hour
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );    // no revisions
```

Comment: What's your user role?

Comment: User Role : Administrator

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, open DevTools and go to the Network tab. Now click the Fetch/XHR filter. Then, click Publish and watch the Network traffic to see if any errors are being returned. That should give you an indication of where things are going wrong. You might see a 500 error returned on the Publish call.

[image]

Comment: it will show like this: https://www.adsinfosys.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Screenshot-367.png

Comment: https://www.adsinfosys.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Screenshot-368.png

Comment: If you google the error, you will see numerous results - potentially that could fix your problem. It ranges from mismatched jQuery versions to variable declarations.. have a look around Google a bit and see what you can find out

Comment: on google I have found these two solution :

1,
function remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']);
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets' );

2, In wp-config.php

define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 3600 );     // autosave 1x per hour
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );    // no revisions

Comment: which i  mentioned but it's not work

Answer (score 0):

I have solved This Issue by following these steps:

1, downloaded Backup of the website using a third party plugin
2, delete WordPress setup from the hosting side
3, install WordPress
4, put a backup file using a third party plugin
5, Boom starts working :)

Comment: Brilliant! Well done.